# How do I properly initialize an array in zsh

Tags: arrays, indexing, zsh

I have a text file made up of 4-digit integers, separated by spaces, that represent line numbers from another file.
After loading an array named "bla", and then trying to print an index of that array, I find that the indexes are the individual "characters" that make up the array.

```
┌──(s)-[~]
└─$ bla=$(grep -n "vfV" Programming/SITEhtml.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/:/ /' | tr -d '\n\r' | awk '{print "("$0")"}')  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(s)-[~]
└─$ echo $bla[@]
(2929 2998 3067 3136 3205 3274 3343 3412 3481 3550 3619 3688 3757 3826 3895 3964 4033 4102 4171 )
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(s)-[~]
└─$ echo $bla[1]
(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(s)-[~]
└─$ echo $bla[10]
8

When I load the array from the CLI instead of the script, I am able to access the indexes properly as shown below.

┌──(s)-[~]
└─$ bla=(2929 2998 3067 3136 3205 3274 3343 3412)                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(s)-[~]
└─$ echo $bla[5]                                 
3205
```

I originally used "bla=$(cat FILE)" to load the array, and when that failed I tried several other print commands that all failed in the same way. mapfile and readarray I believe are not present in zsh.
Can someone point me in the right direction. Much appreciate any help.

Comment: I do believe you pointed me in the right direction. Still stumped, but with direction. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

`(...)` is not an array literal; it's part of the syntax of the assignment itself.

Given that the output is a space-separated string of integers, you can set the shell's ordinary field splitting produce the set of integers to add to the array.

```
bla=( $(grep -n "vfV" Programming/SITEhtml.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/:/ /' | tr -d '\n\r')  )
```